# Mule MEL usage and ExceptionUtils.containsType(exception, type)

Tags: java, exception, mule

My mule flow has a Catch Exception Strategy like below:

```
<catch-exception-strategy when="org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.containsType(exception, IllegalArgumentException.class)"
                doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
    <logger message="IllegalArgumentException occurred" level="INFO" doc:name="logInfo" />
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

The expression `org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.containsType(exception, IllegalArgumentException.class)` sends **null** as second argument to the method `containsType` of the class `org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils`. When I changed the expression to `org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.containsType(exception, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.class)`, this time mule says the expression is wrong and throws an exception.

So my question is why the expression `org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.containsType(exception, IllegalArgumentException.class)` sends null to second argument?

Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement a different treatment for each type of Exception you can use the "choice-exception-strategy". Here you have an example:

```
<flow name="Sample_Flow">
...
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy" when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException)]">
            <set-variable variableName="errorStatusCode" value="404" doc:name="Set status code"/>
            <set-variable variableName="errorReasonPhrase" value="Not Found" doc:name="Set reason phrase"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <rollback-exception-strategy doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Unknown error"/>
        </rollback-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

In the case of your specific implementation you can try just using "IllegalArgumentException" instead of "llegalArgumentException.class":

```
<catch-exception-strategy when="org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.containsType(exception, IllegalArgumentException)">
    <logger message="IllegalArgumentException occurred #[exception.getCauseException().getClass()] - #[IllegalArgumentException]: #[org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.containsType(exception.getCauseException(), IllegalArgumentException)]" level="INFO" doc:name="logInfo" />
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

After the analysis I found that the expression "IllegalArgumentException.class" returns null, but the expression "IllegalArgumentException" returns the class.

You can find more information in the next link:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/choice-exception-strategy

Comment: I know very well about Choice Exception Strategy. Can you please provide only relevant answer?

Comment: Use the expression that is in the example, change the package if necessary:  
when="#[exception.causedBy(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)]"

Comment: Remember that the answers are for you and for others that could have a similar problem so the answer has to be complete. And sometimes it's better to recommend the best practices according to the documentation and experience.

Comment: Ok, I've been using an expression like `#[exception.causedBy(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)]`. My question here is why the expression `org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.containsType(exception, IllegalArgumentException.class)` sends null to second argument? Can you please tell me if you know?

Comment: What version of Mule are you using?, are you using a "choice-exception-strategy" before the "catch-exception-strategy"?. I'd like to replicate the error for analysis.

Comment: Mule version 3.7. Yes I used choice before catch-exception-strategy